# Using rmic gives me error, when trying to create stub and skeleton for Remote Method Invocation

Tags: java, rmi, rmic

I am learning to use RMI in Java, and have been following this GeeksForGeeks tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remote-method-invocation-in-java/.

In step 3, I need to use the rmic tool to create a stub and skeleton, but when I use it together with my implementation class, I get the error:

"The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports rmic. Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java."

Afterwards I tried installing jdk 21, but still got the error.

Anyone who knows how to fix it?

I use MacOS 13.2.1.

Comment: `rmic` has been deprecated in Java 13 and removed in Java 15. You simply don't need it anymore. Just skip step 3.

Comment: And skeletons have been obsolete since 1998. Don’t use third-party tutorials when Oracle have a perfectly good one.

Comment: I see, thank you!